# Refer to group inside group with Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find a regex that groups a word that ends on two identical symbols followed by 'ter' and splits it on the two symbols.
Example: The word 'Letter' should be grouped into 'Let' and 'ter'.
I'm using python and this is what i've gotten so far:

```
match = re.search(r'(\w*)((\w)\1(er$))', str)
print match.group(1) #should print 'Let'
print match.group(2) #should print 'ter'
```

The problem is that the (\w)\1 doesn't refer to the right group, because it's a group inside a group. How is this solved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean two identical symbols followed by `er`?

Comment: You did not explain what the expression is *actually* supposed to do. I can't imagine you're trying to split the word `Letter` into halves and it's close to impossible to guess your intentions from your attempt.

Comment: @Tomalak our names are very similar

Comment: I want the first group to be everything until and including the first of two identical symbols, the second group the second identical symbol followed by 'er'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm using named groups as that makes referencing them easier:

```
import re
pattern = r"""
          \b(?P<first_part>\w*(?P<splitter>\w))   # matches starting at a word boundary
          (?P<last_part>(?P=splitter)er\b)        # matches the last letter of the first group
                                                  # plus 'er' if followed by a word boundary
          """
matcher = re.compile(pattern, re.X)
print matcher.search('letter').groupdict()
# out: {'first_part': 'let', 'last_part': 'ter', 'splitter': 't'}
```

Comment: Without named groups it would look like: `re.search(r'(\w*(\w))(\2er$)', 'letter').groups()` but I don't see any way to reference a non capture group so the splitter will still be at index `1`

Comment: Well, non-capture group means it cannot be referenced, not even within the regular expression.

Comment: this would be the only solution then... unless `regex` module somehow has support for that

Answer (score 2):

> I want the first group to be everything until and including the first of two identical symbols, the second group the second identical symbol followed by 'er'

That would be:

```
match = re.search(r'(\w*(\w)(?=\2))(\w*er$)', str)

print match.groups()
# -> ('Let', 't', 'ter')
```