# Regex - capture groups inside group

Tags: regex

I have a file text including this content:

```
define host {
  use            host-template
  host_name      server-01
  display_name   server-01-display-name
  address        10.0.0.1
  _CUSTOMEREMAIL customer01@mail.com
  _LBZ           LBZ#10178541
}

define service {
  use                  host-template
  host_name            server-02
  service_description  server-02
  servicegroups        wlan
  display_name         server-02
  _LBZ                 LBZ#425964
  _TARGETIP            10.0.0.2
  _CUSTOMEREMAIL customer5@mail.com
}

define service {
  use                  host-template
  host_name            server-03
  service_description  server-03
  servicegroups        wlan
  display_name         server-04
  _LBZ                 LBZ#421264
  _TARGETIP            10.0.0.3
  _CUSTOMEREMAIL customer01@mail.com
}

define host {
  use            host-template
  host_name      server-04
  display_name   server-04
  address        10.0.0.4
  _CUSTOMEREMAIL customer02@mail.com
  _LBZ           LBZ#12300541
}
```

**Task:**
The server02 must be found by parameter "_LBZ" - in this case 425964. Once the define found, it should also capture parameters "host_name", "_LBZ" and '_CUSTOMEREMAIL'.

**Wished result:**

- server-02
- 425964
- customer5@mail.com

Can you help me, please? I am sitting here the second day with this expression.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refer to group inside group with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496540/refer-to-group-inside-group-with-regex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do so:

```
{(?=[^}]*?host_name\s*([^\s]+))(?=[^}]*?_LBZ\s*LBZ#(425964))(?=[^}]*?_TARGETIP\s*([^\s]+))
```

See the [online](https://regex101.com/r/yDguub/1) demo:

---

The first group will be `host_name`, the second `_LBZ` and the last `_CUSTOMEREMAIL`.

---

- `{`: Matches `{`.
- `(?=)`: Positive lookahead.

  - `[^}]*?`: Matches any character other than `}`, between zero and unlimited times, as few as possible.
  - `host_name`: Matches `host_name`.
  - `\s*`: Matches any number of whitespaces.
  - `()`: Capturing group

    - `[^\s]+`. Matches any character other than a whitespace, between one and unlimited times, as much as possible.

The other two lookaheads are constructed similarly, to capture the other parameters.